# import scipy.signal hangs server

Tags: python, apache, flask, scipy

I have a flask server running via apache on AWS, majority is functional programming/APIs for a mobile application. I have to do signal processing for the app, so scipy is essential.

I can `import scipy` without stalling, however, a call to `scipy.signal` will produce errors at the API level where any module therein is required.

Solutions I've tried:

`import scipy` call to `scipy.signal` produces apache log error `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'signal'` However, `import scipy` does not hang server for other APIs. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581593/attributeerror-module-object-scipy-has-no-attribute-misc/56289235) doesn't work as the below imports are unavailable.

`import scipy.signal`

`import scipy.signal as ss`

`from scipy import signal as ss`

`from scipy.signal import savgol_filter, find_peaks`

**All of the above combinations hang server**

`pip install scipy --no-binary :all:`  [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430154/python-script-stuck-at-import)

**Many thanks in advance!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Please check the AWS python runtime scipy version

Comment: Scipy Version 1.6.2

Comment: Thanks for the response, [@youDaily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6227912/youdaily) have you run into this issue with specific versions? 1.6.2 is the latest and doesn't seem to have documented related issues: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.6.2.html